# Best quality/price shared Web Hosting

Tags: mysql, php, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I'm looking for a web hosting to my iPhone app.

My needs are as following:

```
* PHP5
* MySQL5
* curl
* shared SSL
* CRON
* Fast support
* Money back
```

What do you think about those 2: IX Web Hosting and HostGator?

Do you recommend working with one of them?

I appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of forums dedicated to this, such as Webhostingtalk.com.  This is not a review site and these general  questions are better suited elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I've moved several domains over to HostGator's "Baby" plan recently, and have been very happy with their service. Their support has been very responsive - immediate response with their online chat, and < 1hr response via email. At request, they'll enable ssh access to your account, which is a big plus for me. That also speaks highly of their security, as it significantly limits the number of accounts that are able to be accessed via ssh. I have also noticed that they seem to keep their host load at a reasonable level, with no discernable performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

We're on [WebHostingPad](http://www.webhostingpad.com) and have been very surprised by the quality of support (by Techs who live in Chicago, and speak English) while having a very low price, with very reasonable features.

My only gripe is that they're very willing to do non-standard configurations, but they don't advertise it on their website. If you want multiple domains, shared SSL, or any normal stuff you don't see listed on the site, ask; they're probably glad to do it.

Answer (score -3):

This is kind of a moot question since so many plans are exactly the same since they all use the standard cPanel thing.   The answer to this question lies in whether or not there are any plans out there that are better than cPanel.

Comment: Shared hosting comparisons have *many* more variables than what control panel they use. Available throughput, host CPU loading, I/O contention, support responsiveness/cluefulness, etc. to name a few.